# Select entries into nested data structure

Tags: google-bigquery

I have several temporary tables in BigQuery (created via the WITH statement) and want to combine them in the result statement as a nested data structure.

Here is an example, where the final select obviously does not work:

```
with data as (
  select 10 as points UNION ALL
  select 12 as points UNION ALL
  select 20 as points
),
stuff as (
  select 1 as foo, 2 as bar
)

select 
  foo, bar,
  (select * from data) as subTable
from stuff
```

I'd like to generate output that looks like this (json notation for brevity):

```
{
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2,
  subTable: [
    {points: 10}, {points: 12}, {points: 20}
  ]
}
```

How can I achieve this and is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yet another option for this is

```
#standardSQL
SELECT foo, bar,
  (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(data) FROM data) AS subTable
FROM stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Allright I figured it out by myselve.
There are two main ingredients: `ARRAY` and `SELECT AS STRUCT`

```
select 
  foo, bar,
  ARRAY(select as struct * from data) as subTable
from stuff
```

The `ARRAY` function call creates an error from the result, the `SELECT AS STRUCT` converts the result into a structure which is than nested inside.